# Terminal black screen after deleting and reinstalling Node and npm

Tags: command-line, nodejs, npm

I was facing a problem with Node.js, so I decided to uninstall npm and node completely and reinstall them.  Now I have a black terminal with no text, and I'm not able to type anything either.

I haven't been able to find a solution on the Internet.

I tried to restart my PC, but that wasn't enough so I also uninstalled console trying to install it again.  I couldn't reinstall it, so I installed:

- Qterminal
- konsole
- Mate terminal

But all have had the the same problem.

I also tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, but it does nothing but lock my PC.

Any solutions please?

Answer (score -1):

i didn't find any solutions so i tried this it's not exactly what i was looking for but it works my terminal it's working again and my old files are there too

https://youtube.com/watch?v=ptF2RUehbKs&t=273s

Comment: Please edit your answer and add the steps here, thanks!

Comment: simply i deleted and formatted the root partition and bingo the default terminal simulator is there again without deleting my personal data